# Android + Linux Chroot + Node.js = Run your node.js app on phone

Tags: javascript, android, node.js

I got all the steps from the [article](http://mitchtech.net/node-js-on-android-linux/) and followed to do the same on the Android phone.

Now my question is will I be able host some web pages and use Android phone as a web server. If any one tried please let me the solution for hosting web-site and the performance.

---

Update: Able to host on IP: `127.0.0.1`. But, Does anyone tried to use phone as a fully fledged web server, I mean to get an address of external IPv4?

Comment: Keep in mind that even if you set it up correctly, your cell service provider might have a firewall that will block incoming connections.

Comment: If network provider blocks, then what service is actually provided? only to browser through net? I have hosted on machine it works with same network provider.. So, if its on mobile. what makes difference to network provider to block incoming requests? I believe It cant be blocked that way.. But thanks for your time in understanding & for your kind inputs...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wanted to do something similar with a little more flexibility. I wanted to be able to run any kind of server on my android.

This is the approach I went with.

1. Setup [Debian Kit](http://sven-ola.dyndns.org/repo/debian-kit-en.html) on your Android (this basically runs a full debian linux distribution on your android)
2. Setup Node.js on the debain environment (just like you would on any linux distribution)
3. Run your server!!!!

Since you have a full debian distribution on your phone, what you can do with it is limitless. I was able to setup remote desktop with an ssh server, allowing me to remotely manage the debain server on my android. In your situation, you could setup a web server or even use node.js for your web server on your android.

Hope this helps :)